# why do we use 0dh,0ah after msg1 db in this statement :msg1 db 0dh, 0ah, "ENTER A CHOICE $";

Tags: tasm

```
DATA segment
    msg1 db 0dh, 0ah, "ENTER A CHOICE $";
    msg2 db 0dh, 0ah, "1.Addition $";
    msg3 db 0dh, 0ah, "2.Subtraction $"; 
    msg4 db 0dh, 0ah, "3.Exit $";
    msg5 db 0dh, 0ah, "Enter the first number $";
    msg6 db 0dh, 0ah, "Enter the second number $";
    msg7 db 0dh, 0ah, "Result $";
    msg8 db 0dh, 0ah, "Enter a valid input $";
    msg9 db 0dh, 0ah, "$";
    buffer Db ?;
    ten dw 0010;
    hun dw 0100;
    tho dw 1000;
    rem dw ?;
DATA ends

CODE segment
assume CS:CODE,DS:DATA
start:

    him proc
        MOV AX,DATA; 
        MOV DS,AX; 

        MOV DX, OFFSET msg1;
        MOV AH, 09H;
        INT 21h;
        MOV DX, OFFSET msg2;
        MOV AH, 09H;
        INT 21h;
        MOV DX, OFFSET msg3;
        MOV AH, 09H;
        INT 21h;
        MOV DX, OFFSET msg4;
        MOV AH, 09H;
        INT 21h;
        MOV DX, OFFSET msg9;
        MOV AH, 09H;
        INT 21h;

        mov ah, 01h;
        int 21h;

        cmp al, 33h;
        je ex;
        cmp al, 31h;
        je addfunc;
        cmp al, 32h;
        je subfunc;
        cmp al, 33h;
        jg errfunc
        cmp al, 31h;
        jl errfunc

        proc read
            mov ah,01
            int 21h
            sub al,48
            mul ten
            mov buffer,al      
            mov ah,01           
            int 21h
            sub al,48
            add buffer,al
            ret                 ;number in buffer 
        endp

        errfunc proc
            mov dx, offset msg8
            mov ah, 09h
            int 21h
            call him
        endp

        ex proc
            MOV AH,4CH 
            INT 21H 
        endp

        addfunc proc
            MOV DX, OFFSET msg5;
            MOV AH, 09H;
            INT 21h;
            call read
            mov cl,buffer
            MOV DX, OFFSET msg6;
            MOV AH, 09H;
            INT 21h;
            call read
            mov bl,buffer
            MOV DX, OFFSET msg7;
            MOV AH, 09H;
            INT 21h;
            add cl,bl;
            mov al,cl
            mov ah,00
            call write
            call him
        endp

        subfunc proc
            MOV DX, OFFSET msg5;
            MOV AH, 09H;
            INT 21h;
            call read
            mov cl,buffer
            MOV DX, OFFSET msg6;
            MOV AH, 09H;
            INT 21h;
            call read
            mov bl,buffer
            MOV DX, OFFSET msg7;
            MOV AH, 09H;
            INT 21h;
            sub cl,bl;
            mov al,cl
            mov ah,00
            call write
            call him
        endp

        proc write;assuming value is stored in ax
            mov dx,0000
            div tho
            mov rem,dx
            add al,48
            mov dl,al
            mov ah,02h
            int 21h

            mov ax,rem
            mov dx,0000
            div hun
            mov rem,dx
            add al,48
            mov dl,al
            mov ah,02h
            int 21h

            mov ax,rem
            mov dx,0000
            div ten
            mov rem,dx
            add al,48
            mov dl,al
            mov ah,02h
            int 21h

            mov ax,rem
            mov dx,0000
            add al,48
            mov dl,al
            mov ah,02h
            int 21h

            ret         
        endp
    endp

CODE ends

end start
```

Answer (score 3):

MS-DOS needs two characters to perform a cursor jump to the beginning of the next line: `0dh`(Carriage Return, abbr. CR) & `0ah` (Line Feed, abbr. LF), usually abbreviated as `CrLf`. The first character causes the cursor just to jump to the beginning of the line, the second character let the cursor move to the next line. You can play with the definitions (omit `0ah`, omit `0dh`, omit both) and observe the result.

The CrLf at the beginning of `msg1` wouldn't be necessary for the first use, but `msg1` is part of a loop. `result ...` has no CrLf at its end, so `msg` must have it at its start.